# Variables in custom python module

Tags: python, variables, module

I am making my own custom python module called zoro, and I want to enable people making a variable, and the variable is equal to a function in my module, but how do I make that?

I've already tried looking in to the code of other modules like turtle, and turtle used the self argument, so I tried to use that, but it said `TypeError: win() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`.

Code of my program to test the module:

```py
import zoro

test = zoro.win("test","black",500,500)
test.zoro.winTitle("test2")
```

Code of my module:

```py
from tkinter import *


def win(title,bg,w,h):
    root = Tk()
    root.title(title)
    root.config(bg=bg)
    root.geometry(str(w) + "x" + str(h))
    return root
def winTitle(title):
    root.title(title)
```

I want to do like:

```py
test = zoro.win("test","black",500,500)
test.zoro.winTitle("test2")
```

Comment: the code snippet you have shared, should work correctly; and does work correctly for me..

Comment: I didn't said it didn't work, I want the people create variables and then use them later.

Comment: It sounds like you are describing classes, which is where `self` comes in to play.

Comment: No I am not, I am just saying that self didn't work

Comment: It seems as if you want to be able to use the `root` variable in the `win` method from outside the module. If so, why not just `return root` at the end of the function?

Comment: @Ernxst what if the user doesn't want to call it root, but wants to call it something else?

Comment: @BEOfficial It doesn't matter what the user wants to call it, in your `win` function you have called the tkinter window `root`

Comment: @Ernxst My code of the program test: 
`import zoro

test = zoro.win("test","black",500,500)
test.zoro.winTitle("test")`

Module code:
`from tkinter import *


def win(title,bg,w,h):
    root = Tk()
    root.title(title)
    root.config(bg=bg)
    root.geometry(str(w) + "x" + str(h))
    return root
def winTitle(title):
    root.title(title)
`

Comment: @BEOfficial Firstly, that is very difficult to read, update your question to include that. Secondly, if you have already returned `root` what is your problem? The user can already use it as a normal variable.

Comment: but I want them to use the zoro functions, now it gives an error that zoro is unknown in tkinter.

Comment: Your driver is just wrong. The object returned by `zoro.win` doesn't have  an attribute named `zoro`. This is in addition to the fact that there is no global variable `root` for `winTitle` to use.

Comment: @chepner so how do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want your driver to work with the module as currently defined, you need a global variable named `root` for `winTitle` to use. In addition, the object returned by `win` doesn't have an attribute named `zoro`.

```
import zoro

zoro.root = zoro.win("test", "black", 500, 500)
zoro.winTitle("test2")
```

That said, your module should be fixed to avoid global variables in the first place.

```
from tkinter import *


def win(title, bg, w, h):
    root = Tk()
    root.title(title)
    root.config(bg=bg)
    root.geometry(str(w) + "x" + str(h))
    return root


def winTitle(root, title):
    root.title(title)
```

Then your driver will look like

```
import zoro

test = zoro.win("test", "black", 500, 500)
zoro.winTitle(test, "test2")
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Question**:

What you want to do is called `inheritance`.
For example:

> zoro.py

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, title, bg, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.title(title)
        self.geometry('{}x{}'format(width, height)
        self.config(bg=bg)
```

> **Usage**

```
import zoro

class MyApp(zoro.App):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("test","black",500,500)

        # Change title
        self.title('my new title')

        # Add further widgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, but I like the answer below more, I'm sorry.